# LFTP mirror upload only non existing files to remote directory

Tags: bash, shell-script, ftp, lftp

Every 5 minutes some new files are downloaded via lftp to a local directory. I need to upload to another ftp only the non existing files. My script so far is:

```
#! /bin/bash
today=$(date +%Y%m%d)
today_files="rec."$today"_"
programa_dir="/home/user/local-dir"

# Download files, that do not exist in the local directory
lftp <<EOF
open -u user,pass ftp1
mget "$today_files*" -O $programa_dir
bye
EOF

# Upload the files

lftp <<EOF
open -u user,pass ftp2
lcd $programa_dir
mirror -R
bye
EOF
```

The mirror -R command doesn't recognize that only few files do not exist on the remote directory of the second ftp.

Is there a way to fix that? I need only to check the filename's , not the creation or the modification time of the files.

For the second ftp I tried

```
lftp <<EOF
open -u user,pass ftp2
mput $programa_dir/* -O /
bye
EOF
```

The result was the same - lftp upload all the files, no only the non existing.

Comment: Does -c option (continue) work (`mirror -R -c`)? Maybe it understands to "resume" previous mirror operation by adding only missing files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have access to LFTP at the moment, but I suspect you're looking for the `--only-missing` param, which is only usable with `mirror`.

Try this:

```
lftp <<<EOF
open -u user,pass ftp2
mirror --reverse --only-newer $programa_dir/* /
bye
EOF
```

Comment: You mention the `--only-missing` parameter, however you provide `--only-newer` instead. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 0):

If you add set `xfer:clobber off;` to the lftp command script, it will avoid overwriting existing files.